# Syntax error : SELECT username FROM TAMS WHERE NAME IN caner?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, where-clause, psycopg2

I am getting a syntax error below. However, I could not figure it out. How can I run this query.

myCode:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect( user = "postgres", password = "*****", host = 
"127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT username FROM TAMS WHERE NAME IN {}".format('caner'))
```

error:

```
rows= cur.execute("SELECT username FROM TAMS WHERE NAME IN {}".format('caner'))
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: HATA:  "caner"  yerinde söz dizim hatası
LINE 1: SELECT username FROM TAMS WHERE NAME IN caner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements after `in` should be enclosed with parentheses:

```
"SELECT username FROM TAMS WHERE NAME IN ({})".format('caner')
```

Comment: @sananesanane no problem, consider upvoting / accepting ;)